# jQuery File Upload for Java

Tags: jquery, jsp, file-upload

I am trying to use jQuery File Upload:  http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/
I am using JSP.. Can anybody tell me step by step configuration for this.

Comment: Look at the documentation on this page https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki it has Java examples towards the bottom ... have a go, then if you run into problems come back with specific questions and **your** source code

Comment: Ok I check the documentation..
Now when I Select the Image and click on Start it showing error: Not Found.

Comment: Update your question with your code and the exact error message and details of the problem and people will be able to help

Comment: Thanks @ManseUK , My code is working now :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) It's not different from if plain HTML or jQuery is been used.

Comment: @gauravoli, could you explain me how you did it? I'm using java in my server side, how can I set up the servlets? thanks in advance